# Display array of tags with link using ejs in Node

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, express, ejs

I have an array of tags saved into my MongoDB. I did this by using RegEX to turn comma-separated list of words into an array.

This is the line of code that makes it work:

`newMeme.tags = req.body.tags.replace(/\s/g,'').split(',');`

I have this in my DB:

`"tags": [
        "bike",
        "future"
    ],`

So I want to display them on the frontend using EJS in node but I'm having a problem displaying them as a single entity. In a way that `bike` and `future` has a different anchor link instead of having them both in an anchor link.

This is what I'm currently getting:

`<a href='bike,future'> bike, future </a>`

But this what I really wanted:

`<a href="bike"> bike </a>` and `<a href="future"> future </a>`

In a way that they are both separate entity.

This is my code:

```
<% for(var i=0; i<tags.length; i++) { %>

<p id="tags">

      <a href='"<%=  tags[i]  %>"' style="color: blue"> <%= tags[i]  %>  </a>

</p>

  <% } %>
```

I need your help in making this work.

Thanks.

Comment: could it be that tags[i] value is ['bike', 'future'] ?

Comment: I second that. Check your data again as you appear to have saved it as a string. Odds are you are using mongoose and you did something like `tags: String` when it should be `tags: [String]`. If the schema is incorrect, mongoose saves the "string" and not the "array".

Comment: Hi @HimanshuChaudhary@NeilLunn This is how my schema looks like `tags: [String]`

Comment: Can you check before the loop what you are getting as tags. ?

Comment: bike, future. If I get your question right.

Comment: please log the value of tags and tags[i]

Comment: What I want to do is displaying entity of the array separately.  something like Bike Future.  Removing the comma @HimanshuChaudhary

Comment: try this :
``tags.map(tag=>`<a href=${tag}>${tag}</a>`).reduce((acc,curr)=>acc+curr)``

This should give you desired string.

For more details look for map-reduce in Javascript